# How to convert string to bitmap same height as string length?

Tags: android, string, bitmap, android-canvas

I am able to convert string to bitmap with multiple line also.But how to make a bitmap height respect to string length means now i have to pass length of bitmap.

So,Issue is that if string length is larger then height bitmap height then some character cropped.

My code is below:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
   >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMerge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickMerge"
        android:text="Merge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

java code:-

```
public void onClickMerge(View v) {

              String pathName=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/demoApp";
              File f = new File(pathName,"CameraImg_4.jpg");
              if(f.exists()){
                  Log.e("File ", "file exist");
              }
              else{
                  Log.e("File ", "file not exist");
              }
              Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());  


              Bitmap bitmap2=textAsBitmapMultiline("Hello! How are you? What is going on? ", 80, Color.WHITE,bitmap.getWidth(),50); 

              Bitmap bitmap3=combineImages(bitmap, bitmap2);
              imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap3);

              saveBitmapToFile(pathName+"/merged.jpg", bitmap3);
    }



public Bitmap textAsBitmapMultiline(String mText, float textSize, int textColor,int width,int height){

          Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
          Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
          TextPaint mTextPaint=new TextPaint();
          mTextPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
          mTextPaint.setColor(textColor);

          StaticLayout mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(mText, mTextPaint, canvas.getWidth(), Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

          canvas.save();
          mTextLayout.draw(canvas);
          canvas.restore();

          return image;


    }

      public static Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap s) {
            Bitmap cs = null;
            int width, height = 0;
            int sWidth, sHeight = 0;

            sHeight = s.getHeight();
            if(c.getWidth() > s.getWidth()) { 
                  width = c.getWidth(); 
                  height = c.getHeight() + s.getHeight(); 
                } else { 
                  width = s.getWidth(); 
                  height = c.getHeight() + s.getHeight(); 
                } 


            cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height+30, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);
            comboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null);
            comboImage.drawBitmap(s,2f ,  c.getHeight() , null);
            return cs;
        }
```

Attached Screen shot:-
[image]

if anyone have idea.please help me.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the bitmap using

bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);

Comment: Thanks for reply, but how can i found what is the exact height will be for number of character to scale.Please check the textAsBitmapMultiline() again.what exactly i want to say.